# Jquery "If statements" triggering when statement is not true

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building a small connect four game and when I've set the popup to say "Red/Yellow wins" for every possible combination it's causing an unusual error/bug which i'm not sure about.

If I only have one if statement out of around 65 which there are it works perfectly when I get that combination:

```
var a1 = $(".a1").css("background-color");
var a2 = $(".a2").css("background-color");
etc


if (a1 && a2 && a3 && a4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
    alert("red wins");
    console.log("1");
}
if (a2 && a3 && a4 && a5 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
    alert("red wins");
    console.log("1");
}
```

But when I have 65 of these different combinations they seems to be triggering randomly, and not even requiring  a1,a2,a3,a4 to be true to trigger the if statement (it also sometimes triggers without having four background colors true)

Please note: There's A LOT more code of different vars and ifs

Sorry i'm new to SO & JQ If i missed anything out I'd be happy to edit.

Code for @Scott:
(I know there's going to be thousands of ways this is probably wrong and how I should use sockets but I'm not very good with Jquery and unsure on where to start so I used a lot of AJAX)

```html
<?php

try {
 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_host;dbname=$mysql_db", $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
 
 // Get Game ID/Color/Player
 $gameid = $_GET['gameid'];
 $checkPlayer = "SELECT * FROM c4_games WHERE gameid='$gameid'";
 $result = array();
 foreach ($db->query($checkPlayer) as $player) {
  $result[] = $player;
  $player1 = $result[0][1];
  if ($player1 == 0) {
   $update = "UPDATE c4_games SET p1_connect='1' WHERE gameid='$gameid'";
   $db->exec($update);
   $player = "red";
   echo $player;
  } else {
   $update = "UPDATE c4_games SET p2_connect='1' WHERE gameid='$gameid'";
   $db->exec($update);
   $player = "yellow";
   echo $player;
  }
 }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
 $e->getMessage();
}



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Website Title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
  <!-- Javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body> 
  <table class="c4-table">
   <tr>
    <td class="F1">F1</td>
    <td class="F2">F2</td>
    <td class="F3">F3</td>
    <td class="F4">F4</td>
    <td class="F5">F5</td>
    <td class="F6">F6</td>
    <td class="F7">F7</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="E1">E1</td>
    <td class="E2">E2</td>
    <td class="E3">E3</td>
    <td class="E4">E4</td>
    <td class="E5">E5</td>
    <td class="E6">E6</td>
    <td class="E7">E7</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="D1">D1</td>
    <td class="D2">D2</td>
    <td class="D3">D3</td>
    <td class="D4">D4</td>
    <td class="D5">D5</td>
    <td class="D6">D6</td>
    <td class="D7">D7</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="C1">C1</td>
    <td class="C2">C2</td>
    <td class="C3">C3</td>
    <td class="C4">C4</td>
    <td class="C5">C5</td>
    <td class="C6">C6</td>
    <td class="C7">C7</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="B1">B1</td>
    <td class="B2">B2</td>
    <td class="B3">B3</td>
    <td class="B4">B4</td>
    <td class="B5">B5</td>
    <td class="B6">B6</td>
    <td class="B7">B7</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="A1">A1</td>
    <td class="A2">A2</td>
    <td class="A3">A3</td>
    <td class="A4">A4</td>
    <td class="A5">A5</td>
    <td class="A6">A6</td>
    <td class="A7">A7</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  
  <form class="submit-move" style="display:none;" method="POST" action="submit.php">
   <input type="text" class="move" name="move" />
   <input type="hidden" name="gameid" class="gameid" value="<?php echo $gameid ?>"/>
  </form>
  
  <?php if ($player != "red") { 
  echo '<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("td").click(function() {
     y = 0;
     r = 0;
     $("td").each(function() {
      if ($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 255, 0)") {
       y++;
      }
      if ($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       r++;
      }
     });
     
     if (r > y) {
      r++;
      var column = $(this).attr("class").substring(1,2);
      var a = ".A" + column;
      var b = ".B" + column;
      var c = ".C" + column;
      var d = ".D" + column;
      var e = ".E" + column;
      var f = ".F" + column;
       
      if ($(a).attr("id") != "selected") {
       $(a).css("backgroundColor","yellow");
       $(a).attr("id","selected");
       $(".move").val(a);
      } else if ($(b).attr("id") != "selected"){
       $(b).css("backgroundColor","yellow");
       $(b).attr("id","selected");
       $(".move").val(b);
      } else if ($(c).attr("id") != "selected"){
       $(c).css("backgroundColor","yellow");
       $(c).attr("id","selected");
       $(".move").val(c);
      } else if ($(d).attr("id") != "selected"){
       $(d).css("backgroundColor","yellow");
       $(d).attr("id","selected");
       $(".move").val(d);
      } else if ($(e).attr("id") != "selected"){
       $(e).css("backgroundColor","yellow");
       $(e).attr("id","selected");
       $(".move").val(e);
      } else if ($(f).attr("id") != "selected"){
       $(f).css("backgroundColor","yellow");
       $(f).attr("id","selected");
       $(".move").val(f);
      }

      $.ajax({
       url: "api/submit-yellow.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: $(".submit-move").serialize(),
       success: function(result){
        console.log($(".submit-move").serialize());
          }
       }); 
     } else {
      alert("It isnt your turn!");
     }
     
      // CHECK FOR CONNECT 4
      // REMOVED SOME CODE BECAUSE OF BODY LIMIT ON SO
     
     
    });
    $("td").hover(function() {
     var column = $(this).attr("class").substring(1,2);
     var a = ".A" + column;
     var b = ".B" + column;
     var c = ".C" + column;
     var d = ".D" + column;
     var e = ".E" + column;
     var f = ".F" + column;
     $(a).css("border","1px solid yellow");
     $(b).css("border","1px solid yellow");
     $(c).css("border","1px solid yellow");
     $(d).css("border","1px solid yellow");
     $(e).css("border","1px solid yellow");
     $(f).css("border","1px solid yellow");
    });
    $("td").mouseout(function() {
     var column = $(this).attr("class").substring(1,2);
     var a = ".A" + column;
     var b = ".B" + column;
     var c = ".C" + column;
     var d = ".D" + column;
     var e = ".E" + column;
     var f = ".F" + column;
     $(a).css("border","1px solid black");
     $(b).css("border","1px solid black");
     $(c).css("border","1px solid black");
     $(d).css("border","1px solid black");
     $(e).css("border","1px solid black");
     $(f).css("border","1px solid black");
    }); 
    
    var lastMoveYellow = function load() {
     $.ajax({url:"api/move-yellow.php?gameid="+$(".gameid").val(),success:function(result){
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
      var ids = obj.map(function(el) {
       $($(el.move).css("backgroundColor","yellow"));
      });
     }});
    };
    loadInterval = setInterval(lastMoveYellow, 1000);
    
    var lastMoveRed = function load() {
     $.ajax({url:"api/move-red.php?gameid="+$(".gameid").val(),success:function(result){
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
      var ids = obj.map(function(el) {
       $($(el.move).css("backgroundColor","red"));
       $($(el.move).attr("id","selected"));
      });
     }});
    };
    loadInterval = setInterval(lastMoveRed, 1000);
   });
  </script>';
  } else {
   echo '<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("td").click(function() {
     y = 0;
     r = 0;
     $("td").each(function() {
      if ($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 255, 0)") {
       y++;
      }
      if ($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       r++;
      }
     });
     
     if (r == y) {
      r++;
      var column = $(this).attr("class").substring(1,2);
      var a = ".A" + column;
      var b = ".B" + column;
      var c = ".C" + column;
      var d = ".D" + column;
      var e = ".E" + column;
      var f = ".F" + column;
       
      if ($(a).attr("id") != "selected") {
       $(a).css("backgroundColor","red");
       $(a).attr("id","selected");
       $(".move").val(a);
      } else if ($(b).attr("id") != "selected"){
       $(b).css("backgroundColor","red");
       $(b).attr("id","selected");
       $(".move").val(b);
      } else if ($(c).attr("id") != "selected"){
       $(c).css("backgroundColor","red");
       $(c).attr("id","selected");
       $(".move").val(c);
      } else if ($(d).attr("id") != "selected"){
       $(d).css("backgroundColor","red");
       $(d).attr("id","selected");
       $(".move").val(d);
      } else if ($(e).attr("id") != "selected"){
       $(e).css("backgroundColor","red");
       $(e).attr("id","selected");
       $(".move").val(e);
      } else if ($(f).attr("id") != "selected"){
       $(f).css("backgroundColor","red");
       $(f).attr("id","selected");
       $(".move").val(f);
      }

       $.ajax({
        url: "api/submit-red.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $(".submit-move").serialize(),
        success: function(result){
          console.log("working");
         }
        });
      } else {
       alert("It isnt your turn!");
      }
      
      
      // CHECK FOR CONNECT 4
      var a1 = $(".a1").css("background-color");
      var a2 = $(".a2").css("background-color");
      var a3 = $(".a3").css("background-color");
      var a4 = $(".a4").css("background-color");
      var a5 = $(".a5").css("background-color");
      var a6 = $(".a6").css("background-color");
      var a7 = $(".a7").css("background-color");
      var b1 = $(".b1").css("background-color");
      var b2 = $(".b2").css("background-color");
      var b3 = $(".b3").css("background-color");
      var b4 = $(".b4").css("background-color");
      var b5 = $(".b5").css("background-color");
      var b6 = $(".b6").css("background-color");
      var b7 = $(".b7").css("background-color");
      var c1 = $(".c1").css("background-color");
      var c2 = $(".c2").css("background-color");
      var c3 = $(".c3").css("background-color");
      var c4 = $(".c4").css("background-color");
      var c5 = $(".c5").css("background-color");
      var c6 = $(".c6").css("background-color");
      var c7 = $(".c7").css("background-color");
      var d1 = $(".d1").css("background-color");
      var d2 = $(".d2").css("background-color");
      var d3 = $(".d3").css("background-color");
      var d4 = $(".d4").css("background-color");
      var d5 = $(".d5").css("background-color");
      var d6 = $(".d6").css("background-color");
      var d7 = $(".d7").css("background-color");
      var e1 = $(".e1").css("background-color");
      var e2 = $(".e2").css("background-color");
      var e3 = $(".e3").css("background-color");
      var e4 = $(".e4").css("background-color");
      var e5 = $(".e5").css("background-color");
      var e6 = $(".e6").css("background-color");
      var e7 = $(".e7").css("background-color");
      var f1 = $(".b1").css("background-color");
      var f2 = $(".b2").css("background-color");
      var f3 = $(".b3").css("background-color");
      var f4 = $(".b4").css("background-color");
      var f5 = $(".b5").css("background-color");
      var f6 = $(".b6").css("background-color");
      var f7 = $(".b7").css("background-color");


      if (a1 && a2 && a3 && a4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
       console.log("1");
      }
      if (a2 && a3 && a4 && a5 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
       console.log("2");
      }
      if (a3 && a4 && a5 && a6 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
       console.log("3");
      }
      if (a4 && a5 && a6 && a7 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
       console.log("4");
      }
      if (b1 && b2 && b3 && b4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
       console.log("5");
      }
      if (b2 && b3 && b4 && b5 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
       console.log("6");
      }
      if (b3 && b4 && b5 && b6 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
       console.log("7");
      }
      if (b4 && b5 && b6 && b7 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
       console.log("8");
      }
      if (c1 && c2 && c3 && c4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (c2 && c3 && c4 && c5 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (c3 && c4 && c5 && c6 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (c4 && c5 && c6 && c7 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (d1 && d2 && d3 && d4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (d2 && d3 && d4 && d5 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (d3 && d4 && d5 && d6 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (d4 && d5 && d6 && d7 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (e1 && e2 && e3 && e4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (e2 && e3 && e4 && e5 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (e3 && e4 && e5 && e6 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (e4 && e5 && e6 && e7 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (f1 && f2 && f3 && f4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (f2 && f3 && f4 && f5 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (f3 && f4 && f5 && f6 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (f4 && f5 && f6 && f7 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      
      if (a1 && b1 && c1 && d1 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (e1 && b1 && c1 && d1 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (f1 && e1 && c1 && d1 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (a2 && b2 && c2 && d2 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (e2 && b2 && c2 && d2 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (f2 && e2 && c2 && d2 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (a3 && b3 && c3 && d3 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (e3 && b3 && c3 && d3 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (f3 && e3 && c3 && d3 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (a4 && b4 && c4 && d4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (e4 && b4 && c4 && d4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (f4 && e4 && c4 && d4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (a5 && b5 && c5 && d5 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (e5 && b5 && c5 && d5 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (f5 && e5 && c5 && d5 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (a6 && b6 && c6 && d6 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (e6 && b6 && c6 && d6 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (f6 && e6 && c6 && d6 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (a7 && b7 && c7 && d7 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (e7 && b7 && c7 && d7 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (f7 && e7 && c7 && d7 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      
      if (c1 && d2 && e3 && f4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (b1 && c2 && d3 && e4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (c2 && d3 && e4 && f5 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (a1 && b2 && c3 && d4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (b2 && c3 && d4 && f5 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (c3 && d4 && e5 && f6 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (a2 && b3 && d4 && e5 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (b3 && c4 && d5 && e6 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (c4 && d5 && e6 && f7 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (a3 && b4 && c5 && d6 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (b4 && c5 && d6 && e7 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (a4 && b5 && c6 && d7 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      
      if (a4 && b3 && c2 && a1 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (a5 && b4 && c3 && d2 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (b4 && c3 && d2 && e1 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (a6 && b5 && c4 && d3 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (b5 && c4 && d3 && e2 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (c4 && d3 && e2 && f1 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (a7 && b6 && c5 && d4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (b6 && c5 && d4 && e3 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (c5 && d4 && e3 && f2 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (b7 && c6 && d5 && e4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (c6 && d5 && e4 && f3 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
      if (c7 && d6 && e5 && f4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
       alert("red wins");
      }
     });
    
     $("td").hover(function() {
      var column = $(this).attr("class").substring(1,2);
      var a = ".A" + column;
      var b = ".B" + column;
      var c = ".C" + column;
      var d = ".D" + column;
      var e = ".E" + column;
      var f = ".F" + column;
      $(a).css("border","1px solid red");
      $(b).css("border","1px solid red");
      $(c).css("border","1px solid red");
      $(d).css("border","1px solid red");
      $(e).css("border","1px solid red");
      $(f).css("border","1px solid red");
     });
     $("td").mouseout(function() {
      var column = $(this).attr("class").substring(1,2);
      var a = ".A" + column;
      var b = ".B" + column;
      var c = ".C" + column;
      var d = ".D" + column;
      var e = ".E" + column;
      var f = ".F" + column;
      $(a).css("border","1px solid black");
      $(b).css("border","1px solid black");
      $(c).css("border","1px solid black");
      $(d).css("border","1px solid black");
      $(e).css("border","1px solid black");
      $(f).css("border","1px solid black");
     }); 
     
     var lastMoveYellow = function load() {
      $.ajax({url:"api/move-yellow.php?gameid="+$(".gameid").val(),success:function(result){
       var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
       var ids = obj.map(function(el) {
        $($(el.move).css("backgroundColor","yellow"));
        $($(el.move).attr("id","selected"));
       });
      }});
     };
     loadInterval = setInterval(lastMoveYellow, 1000);
     
     var lastMoveRed = function load() {
      $.ajax({url:"api/move-red.php?gameid="+$(".gameid").val(),success:function(result){
       var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
       var ids = obj.map(function(el) {
        $($(el.move).css("backgroundColor","red"));
       });
      }});
     };
     loadInterval = setInterval(lastMoveRed, 1000);
    });
  </script>';
  }
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If any of your a# variables is equal to 0 then that will equate to false.

Comment: Can you post the entire code?  I bet you have a syntax error somewhere which can cause what you are explaining.

Comment: @Scott I posted the entire code. Again it probably is horrible to look at and read but I'm new.

Comment: `if (a1) {` just checked that a1 is set to something (ie. it exists and isn't some variation of false).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (a1 && a2 && a3 && a4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
```

This checks `a1` as a condition itself which I doubt is what. If the intent to check each value against that string, this is what you'd want something like this:

```
if ((a1== "rgb(255, 0, 0)") && (a2== "rgb(255, 0, 0)") && (a3== "rgb(255, 0, 0)")  && (a4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")))
```

Using loops and arrays may be better than writing out a bunch of similar lines. For example something like this may do what you want without having to write out all the lines like you have:

```
for (var i=0; i<winningCombinations.length; i++) {
  var a1=$("."+winningCombinations[i][0]).css("background-color");
  var a2=$("."+winningCombinations[i][1]).css("background-color");
  var a3=$("."+winningCombinations[i][2]).css("background-color");
  var a4=$("."+winningCombinations[i][3]).css("background-color");

  if ((a1== "rgb(255, 0, 0)") && (a2== "rgb(255, 0, 0)") && (a3== "rgb(255, 0, 0)")  && (a4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")))
  {
      // add message here for 4 in a row.
      break; // this will exit the for loop.
  }

}
```

I'd highly suggest creating an array that holds the various combinations you want to check. Consider something like this:

```
var winningCombinations = new Array();
winningCombinations.push({'a1','a2','a3','a4'});
winningCombinations.push({'a2','a3,'a4','a5'});
....
```

Note that I did change the loop to now use a 2-dimensional array as the winningCombinations will have 4 columns in each entry that can be used here.

Comment: I'd recommend that all of the IF statements be converted into 2 nested for loops.

Comment: Ok I fully understand, thank you. Could you give me details to how they break when I have multiple conditions and work with only a single condition

Comment: @Scott I'm really a beginner in jQuery and i'm not sure on how I'd do that, I feel asking in this question would be inappropriate too

Comment: What's the other `for` loop needed? I could see having a pair of `if` inside the loop to see if red or yellow won but the same loop could be used with just one `break` or `return` if there is a winner.

Comment: @ConorReidd, what do you mean by 'break when you have multiple conditions and work with only a single condition'? The expression in the brackets of an `if` have specific rules on how its gets evaluated that wasn't what you initially thought.

Comment: @JBKing if i use a single condition (one of my 65 different if statements) when I play the game of connect 4 and get that exact combination It works  correctly. If i use multiple conditions, they trigger even when I don't get connect 4

Comment: @ConorReidd, have you changed your if code so that it'll work correctly? The `if (a1 && a2 && a3,,,` that you had was the issue as that will just check `a1` itself to evaluate to true or false without taking anything else into account. To combine conditions requires using brackets and proper syntax or else you run the rick of unintended side effects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94227/discussion-between-jb-king-and-conorreidd).

Answer (score 3):

What you are testing is if a1 ,a2, a3 exist and if a4's background colour is red.

I believe what you want to test for is if all of them are red. This would be:

```
if (a1 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)" && a2 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)" && a3 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)" && a4 == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") { ... }
```

what you might want to do is construct a helper function where you pass in an array of objects and test if their background colour is the same. If it is, it will return the colour, else it will return NULL.

e.g.

```
function testColour(objects){
   var colour = null;
   for (var i = 0;i<objects.length;i++){
         if (i == 0){
             //set colour from first one
             colour = objects[i].css("background-color");
         else if (objects[i].css("background-color")!=colour){
             //check if colour is the same as first. If not, return null
             return null;
         }
   }
   //all objects are of the same colour, return colour.
   return colour
}

colour = testColour([$(".a1"),$(".a2"),$(".a3"),$(".a4")])

if (colour!=null){
    //colour wins
    if (colour=="rgb(255,0,0)"){
        alert("Red wins!");
    }else{
        alert("Yellow wins!");
    }
    break;
}
```

To simplify checking all of them you might want to consider your grid as a matrix, then use matrix operations to check for four in a row

```
//define array for conversions between letters and numbers
var nToL = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
//define direction in which a connect 4 is allowed
var allowedVectors = [{"x":1,"y":0},{"x":0,"y":1},{"x":1,"y":1}];
//for each row
for (i=0;i<7;i++){
    //for each column
    for (j=0;j<6;j++){
        //for each allowed vector
        for (v=0;v<allowedVectors.length;v++){
            var currentVector = allowedVectors[v];
            //make sure vector does not go outside grid
            if (i+currentVector.x*3<7||j+currentVector.y*3<6){
                var objectArray = [];
                //create array of objects to test
                for (n=0;n<4;n++){
                    var square = $("."+nToL[j+currentVector.y*n]+(i+1+currentVector.x*n));
                    objectArray.push(square);
                }
                if (testColour(objectArray)!=null){
                    //colour wins
                    if (colour=="rgb(255,0,0)"){
                        alert("Red wins!");
                    }else{
                        alert("Yellow wins!");
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```